# Group Array and add up values within specific range

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array(
        [number] => 50
        [amount] => 0.04
        )

    [1] => Array(
        [number] => 50
        [amount] => 0.04
        )

    [2] => Array(
        [number] => 50
        [amount] => 0.04
        )

    [3] => Array(
        [number] => 100
        [amount] => 0.04
        )

    [4] => Array(
        [number] => 150
        [amount] => 0.04
        )
)
```

I want to add up all amounts whos number are in these ranges 0 to 50, 51 to 100 and 101 to 150.

Required result:
0 to 50 = 0.2 (Add up all 0.04, because number 100 & 150 also has 50's)
51 to 100 = 0.08
101 to 150 = 0.04

Can someone please give me a solution.

Comment: But my requirement is different what you thought. i want to add values of 51-100 & 101 to 150 also in lower ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could also do is specify your ranges in an array. Then loop your array and get the ranges which are lower or equal to than the current number using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). For each range then add the amount using the value from the range as the key:

```
$ranges = [50,100,150];
$result = [];
$items = [
    [
        "number" => 50,
        "amount" => 0.04
    ],
    [
        "number" => 50,
        "amount" => 0.04
    ],
    [
        "number" => 50,
        "amount" => 0.04
    ],
    [
        "number" => 100,
        "amount" => 0.04
    ],
    [
        "number" => 150,
        "amount" => 0.04
    ]
];

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $validRanges  = array_filter($ranges, function($range) use ($item){
        return $range <= $item["number"];
    });
    foreach ($validRanges as $validRange) {
        if (!array_key_exists($validRange, $result)) {
            $result[$validRange] = $item["amount"];
            continue;
        }
        $result[$validRange] += $item["amount"];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [50] => 0.2
    [100] => 0.08
    [150] => 0.04
)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/QYSlk)

Comment: I thought the requirement was that values between 0-50 etc were to be added up, if you changed any of the numbers to (for example) 48, then this value is not counted at all.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to add it to a group of result fields, I've gone with a nested `foreach()` method.  The main thing is that I've defined a `$results` array which defines the start point for that result.

It loops over each item in the source array and then loops over each result field, if the source item is greater than the start of the results then it stops looking and moves onto the next source item...

```
$results = [ [ "from" => 0, "total" => 0],
    [ "from" => 100, "total" => 0],
    [ "from" => 150, "total" => 0]
];
foreach ( $data as $item )  {
    foreach ( $results as $key => $result ) {
        if ( $result["from"] > $item["number"] )    {
            break;
        }
        $results [ $key ]["total"] += $item["amount"];
    }
}

print_r(array_column($results,"total"));
```

prints out

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.2
    [1] => 0.08
    [2] => 0.04
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a combination of `array_reduce` and `array_filter`

```
function toFifty($value)
{
  return $value['number'] >= 0 && $value['number'] < 51;
}

function toHundred($value)
{
  return $value['number'] >= 51 && $value['number'] < 101;
}

function toHundredFifty($value)
{
  return $value['number'] >= 101 && $value['number'] < 151;
}

function sum($carry, $item)
{
    return $carry + $item['amount'];
}

var_dump(array_reduce(array_filter($array, 'toFifty'), 'sum'));
var_dump(array_reduce(array_filter($array, 'toHundred'), 'sum'));
var_dump(array_reduce(array_filter($array, 'toHundredFifty'), 'sum'));
```

Comment: I can't hard code. i want to group by. Its still showing wrong result